# How to generate item variables from total score variable

Tags: stata

I want to simulate the item score from total score.

For example, I have generated the total score, which has scores between `5` and `25`. I would like to distribute this total score to *five* items with each having a `5`-Likert score.

Then I used a `while` loop to check the condition in Stata 15. The code takes took too long to finish looping and I do not know whether I have made a mistake.

Perhaps someone would like to suggest another way to simulate the item score from the total score?

My code:

```
set obs 200

generate id=_n
generate u_i= rnormal(0, 0.5)
generate gr = runiform()>0.5
generate sex = runiform()>0.4
generate age = round(rnormal(65, 10))

expand 5

bysort id: generate time=_n  

generate e_ij = rnormal(0, 1.0)

generate run=_n

*Generate Sum score 5-25

generate y = 3.0 + 2.0*gr + 0.2*age -1.2*sex + 0.5*time + u_i + e_ij

summarize y

replace y = round(y)

*Generate each item

forvalues k = 1(1)5 {
    generate item`k' = runiform(1, 5)
    replace item`k' = round(item`k')
}

egen sum_item=rowtotal(item1 item2 item3 item4 item5)       
generate diff = y - sum_item


*Looping check if y=sum_item    

forvalues a = 1(1)`=_N'  {
    quietly gsort -diff
    while sum_item!=y[`a'] {
        replace sum_item=. if sum_item!=y[_n]

        forvalues k = 1(1)5 {   
           replace item`k' =. if sum_item==.

           replace item`k' = runiform(1, 5) if item`k'==.
           replace item`k' = round(item`k') 
                        }
           replace sum_item= item1 + item2+item3+item4+item5 if sum_item==.
           replace diff = y - sum_item  
           if (sum_item==y[`a']) continue, break
        }
    }
```

The expected data that I would like to have:

[image: The expected data which I would like to have]

As you can see, after running the loop I will always get `2`-`4` cases that the program keep running by generating item score (`item1`-`item5`) until the `diff` variable equals zero.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could loop something like the following (after setting all the items to initial values of 1, since possible values are 1 to 5):

```
capture generate rand_int = 0
replace rand_int = floor( 5 * runiform() + 1 )  // random int, 1 to 5
capture generate cnd = 0

forvalues k = 1(1)5 {
    replace cnd = rand_int == `k' & sum_item < y & item`k' < 6
    replace item`k' = item`k' + 1 if cnd
}

replace sum_item = item1+item2+item3+item4+item5
```

In words, that says is that if `sum_item < y`, then randomly add 1 to one of the items (as long as that item is not already equal to 5), and then you would keep doing it until `sum_item == y` for all rows.

So that's going to converge in roughly 20 iterations if the max value of `y` is 25 and items are from 1 to 5.  I say "roughly" because there is a little waste in here when you add 1 to an item that is already equal to 5.  You could ad some extra code for that, but I wouldn't bother if this is fast enough.  E.g. for high values of `item_sum` it would be more efficient to start with initial values of 5 and randomly subtract 1 until it converges.

I'm not enough of a statistician to say that's the best or even an adequate way to do it, but intuitively to me it seems OK if you want a fairly uniform distribution of values.  If you wanted the modal value to be 4, for example, that's a lot harder and not really a programming question any longer.